# Navigation View in Swift Ui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a problem, when I use a Navigation Link in my Code , Text from Cell becomes centered. That a solution? Thank You!

```
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(0..<1) { _ in
                HStack {Spacer()}
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ChatView(), label: {
                    ConversationCell()
                })
                
                    UserSell()
                
            }
        }.padding(.leading)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.